# c# Design Pattern - interacting with Base

Tags: c#, design-patterns, radix

I have a class `SafeChargeDeposit` inheriting from `BaseExternalDeposit`.
the `BaseExternalDeposit` require in its constructor a variable type `BaseDepositStructure`.

Since It requires `BaseDepositStructure` I cant use its child's elements in  `SafeChargeDeposit`.

this is the code:

```
 abstract class BaseExternalDeposit
    {
        public abstract BaseExternalDepositResult DoDeposit();

        protected BaseDepositStructure depositStructure;

        public BaseExternalDeposit(BaseDepositStructure depositStructure)
        {
            this.depositStructure = depositStructure;
        }
    }


 class SafeChargeDeposit : BaseExternalDeposit
 {
       public SafeChargeDeposit(CreditCardDepositStructure depositStructure):base(depositStructure){}

       public override BaseExternalDepositResult DoDeposit(){

        /////// I CAN USE THIS MEMBER:
        depositStructure.Amount = 50;

        /////// BUT I CANNOT USE THIS MEMBER:
        depositStructure.CreditCardNumber = "123456"; 
       }
 }


public class BaseDepositStructure
    {
        public double Amount = 0.0;
    }

    public class CreditCardDepositStructure : BaseDepositStructure
    {
        public string CreditCardNumber = string.Empty;
    }
```

I understand why I can use depositStructure.Amount and can't use depositStructure.CreditCardNumber  ...
But what is wrong with my design here? how can I solve this issue and keep the flexibility of using Bases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
interface IBaseExternalDepositResult
{
};  // eo interface BaseExternalDepositResult

interface IDeposit
{
    void Deposit();
};

// class BaseExternalDeposit<>
abstract class BaseExternalDeposit<B> : IDeposit where B : BaseDepositStructure
{
    private B depositStructure_;
    protected abstract IBaseExternalDepositResult DepositImpl();
    protected B Structure { get { return depositStructure_; } }

    public BaseExternalDeposit(B depositStructure)
    {
        depositStructure_ = depositStructure;
    }   // eo ctor


    // IDeposit
    void Deposit()
    {
        DepositImpl();
    }
}   // eo class BaseExternalDeposit<B>


// class SafeChargeDeposit
class SafeChargeDeposit : BaseExternalDeposit<CreditCardDepositStructure>
{
    protected override IBaseExternalDepositResult DepositImpl()
    {
        Structure.Amount = 50;
        Structure.CreditCardNumber = "123456";
    }   // eo DepositImpl


    public SafeChargeDeposit(CreditCardDepositStructure depositStructure)
        : base(depositStructure)
    {
    }
}   // eo class SafeChargeDeposit


public class BaseDepositStructure
{
    public double Amount = 0.0;
}

public class CreditCardDepositStructure : BaseDepositStructure
{
    public string CreditCardNumber = string.E
```

Comment: It does how ever change the possibilities of using BaseExternalDepodsition<T>. In OPs code BaseExternalDeposit bed = new SafeChargeDeposit(); is valid howvever BaseExternalDeposit<BaseDepositStructure> bed = new SafeChargeDeposit(); will not work

Comment: @RuneFS, if polymorphism is required, an interface base class can be used.  I really don't see the issue.  Given the fact that `DoDeposit()` and it's result does not rely on the generic parameter, this could even be in the interface class (if it was required as a public method).  I do not believe there are any issues with this answer that can't be resolved! :)

Comment: I never said there was something that could be resolved. I simply said that there was a common scenario you didn't cater for. Which as you say can be handle with an interface. But since you haven't done that you're code is functionally not equivalent to the one OP posted. Whether or not that's an issue to OP only he knows. I personally seriously hope it is because if you _always_ relies on the concrete class and not the most generic base class/interface that's usually a strong smell that somethings wrong. That has nothing to do with your solution of course

Comment: @RuneFS, you are right of course that it is important to be clear on these things.  I've updated the code to clean it up a bit and provide an interface base.

Comment: @RuneFS - So, you suggest that DoDeposit will be from an interface and not from a Base? thanks